# My query works in SQL Server 2017, but it does not work in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I am trying to replace values in a delimited list that I am stuck with, and I know it is against the normalization. However I have no choice. I have written a query that replaces a value in delimited list and avoids duplication if the value I am trying to replace it with already exists.

My query works perfectly fine in SQL Server 2017, but it does not work in SQL Server 2014. I get an error message. I need this query to work in SQL Server 2014. I would appreciate it a lot. My query is given below along with fiddle execution link. The error message is

> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1 Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>
> Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near 'inputs'.
>
> Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near 'replacement'.

[https://dbfiddle.uk/rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9eb71e1e90b07c8c150004dc9a6d5107](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9eb71e1e90b07c8c150004dc9a6d5107)

```
UPDATE test
SET appValue = TRIM(',' FROM REPLACE(inputs.expression, inputs.pattern, replacement.value))
FROM test
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT
         ',' + appValue + ','  AS expression,
         ',' + '406'    + ','  AS pattern,
         ',' + '506'    + ','  AS replacement
    ) inputs
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT
         CASE 
            WHEN inputs.expression LIKE '%' + inputs.replacement + '%'
               THEN ','
               ELSE inputs.replacement
         END) replacement(value)
WHERE
    inputs.expression LIKE '%' + inputs.pattern + '%'
```

Comment: well, the `TRIM` function was introduced in SQL Server 2017, so it won't work in SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 2):

The [`TRIM()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is new for Sql Server 2017. For older versions of Sql Server you have to use the older `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` functions, which don't have the same `characters FROM string` syntax, or other more complicated string functions like `CHARINDEX()` and `SUBSTRING()`.

The easiest thing here might be to `REPLACE()` all spaces with a special character you know is not part of your data, then `REPLACE()` all commas with a space, trim the spaces using the old `LTRIM()`/`RTRIM()` functions, `REPLACE()` the spaces back to commas again, and `REPLACE()` the special character back to spaces.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(column, ' ', '|'), ',', ' '))), ' ', ','), '|', ' ')
```

Or if you know there is likely to be just one extra trailing or leading comma, you can test for that and use SUBSTRING() to cut out just that character.